# How to remove space between image, and fix the :hover selector?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a page and I have encountered couple issues. The first issue is that the spacing between images is different each time. and the second issue is when I hover on one image, all the texts of the other images show as well.

```
<style>

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: black;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -270px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}



.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.text {
  background-color: #81282A;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

</style>

<div class="container">
  <p>
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0254/5067/6317/files/applestore_large.png?v=1562167947" height="480x480" width="1179x1179" alt="" />
  </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>
    <iframe width="1179x1179" height="480x480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zhEAhiPo5GE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">    
    </iframe>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0254/5067/6317/files/smart_large.jpg?v=1562170226" alt="" class="image" width="1179x1179" height="480x480" />
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">Check out our custom <br /> smart kitchen gallery here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0254/5067/6317/files/laptopRepair_large.jpg?v=1561171348" class="image" width="1179x1179" height="480x480" alt="" />
  </p>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">We Service &amp; Repair All          <br /> Types of Electronics</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  <p>
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0254/5067/6317/files/electric_car_large.jpeg?v=1562179941" width="1179x1179" height="480x480" alt="" />
  </p>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">Electric Car Charging <br />          Base Installation
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect the images to have the same spacing (small space), and the text only shows when I hover over its own image

Comment: Do you realize the whole contents of the <style> tag block are commented out?

Comment: Few issues. your height/width attributes are incorrect. I'm also not getting the hover issue you describe. and the padding issue seems to be attributed to your inconsistent paragraph wrapping tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things things that need addressing in your code to get the issues sorted:

1) The height and width of your images and iframe should not be defined as width="1179x1179" height="480x480". Instead use width="1179" height="480"

2) The padding on the text class was creating the extra space between the images. To fix this, I took the images out of the paragraph tags. Since paragraphs have a default margin, I placed margins instead on the container class. I also positioned the container class as relative, and then positioned the middle class as being absolute, in relation to the container element.

3) The text was displaying on hover over the incorrect image because the middle class had top position of -270px. I just gave this a position of 40%. This may not be the exact positioning you want, but you can play around with the values to get what you want

```css
.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 26px 0px;
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: black;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.text {
  background-color: #81282A;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1179/480" height="480" width="1179" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <iframe height="480" width="1179" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zhEAhiPo5GE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">    
        </iframe>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1179/480" alt="" class="image" height="480" width="1179" />
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">
      Check out our custom <br /> smart kitchen gallery here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1179/480" class="image" height="480" width="1179" alt="" />
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">
      We Service &amp; Repair All
      <br /> Types of Electronics
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1179/480" height="480" width="1179" alt="" />
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">
      Electric Car Charging <br /> Base Installation
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```